# Trying to invoke a stored procedure with LINQ results in error

Tags: vb.net

My application produces this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user..This started after I added a stored proc in my dbml file. It works fine in my local enviroment, but throws that error when deploy to staging sever. the user it displays is foreign to me

Answer (score 0):

Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97594/login-failed-for-user-username-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-with-linq-i) solve your problem? It talks about moving the connection string from the app.config to the web.config

Comment: My web config matches my local config. No luck yet

Comment: The problem had nothing to do with the stored proc, thanks everyone.