# Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, web-applications, iis-6

I know this is almost a duplicate of : [The error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'" in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269706/the-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-iusr-in-asp-net-and-sql-server-2) and [Login failed for user 'username' - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with LINQ in external project / class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97594/login-failed-for-user-username-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-with-linq-i) but some things don't add up compared to other appliations on my server and I am not sure why.

**Boxes being used:**

Web Box
SQL Box
SQL Test Box

**My Application:**

I have an ASP.NET Web Application, which references a class library that uses LINQ-to-SQL. Connection string set up properly in the class library. As per [Login failed for user 'username' - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with LINQ in external project / class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97594/login-failed-for-user-username-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-with-linq-i) I also added this connection string to the Web Application.

The connection string uses SQL credentials as so (in both web app and class library):

```
 <add name="Namespace.My.MySettings.ConnectionStringProduction"
        connectionString="Data Source=(SQL Test Box);Initial Catalog=(db name);Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This connection confirmed as working via adding it to Server Explorer. This is the connection string my .dbml file is using.

**The problem:**

I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.
```

Now referencing this [The error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'" in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269706/the-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-iusr-in-asp-net-and-sql-server-2) it says that's really the local network service and using any other non-domain name will not work.

But I am confused because I've checked both SQL Box and SQL Test Box SQL Management Studio and both have `NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE` under Security -> Logins, at the database level, that isn't listed under Security -> Users, but at the database level Security -> Users I have the user displayed in the connection string.

At NTFS level on web server, the permissions have NETWORK SERVICE has full control.

The reason why I am confused is because I have many other web applications on my Web Server, that reference databases on both SQL Box and SQL Test Box, and they all work. But I cannot find a difference between them and my current application, other than I am using a class library. Will that matter? Checking NTFS permissions, setup of Security Logins at the server and databases levels, connection string and method of connecting (SQL Server credentials), and IIS application pool and other folder options, are all the same.

Why do these applications work without adding the machinename$ to the permissions of either of my SQL boxes? But that is what the one link is telling me to do to fix this problem.

Comment: So to recap, you're not using a database user? We create one and can toggle between it and SA depending on what we need to do...

Comment: In the connection string I am using a database user, which I created in the Security -> Logins area, added it to the Security -> users of the database, and gave it dbo permissions. Which is how I did all my other apps too.

Comment: Here's a clear explanation from MSDN using the default machine name, basically you just add the domain/machine$ to sql without hitting search. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

NETWORK SERVICE and LocalSystem will authenticate themselves always as the correpsonding account locally (builtin\network service and builtin\system) but both will authenticate as the machine account remotely.

If you see a failure like `Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'` it means that a process running as NETWORK SERVICE or as LocalSystem has accessed a remote resource, has authenticated itself as the machine account and was denied authorization.

Typical example would be an ASP application running in an app pool set to use NETWORK SERVICE credential and connecting to a remote SQL Server: the app pool will authenticate as the *machine* running the app pool, and is this machine account that needs to be granted access.

When access is denied to a machine account, then access must be granted to the machine account. If the server refuses to login 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$', then you must grant login rights to 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$' not to NETWORK SERVICE. Granting access to NETWORK SERVICE would allow a **local** process running as NETWORK SERVICE to connect, not a remote one, since the remote one will authenticate as, you guessed, DOMAIN\MACHINE$.

If you expect the asp application to connect to the remote SQL Server as a SQL login and you get exceptions about DOMAIN\MACHINE$ it means you use Integrated Security in the connection string. If this is unexpected, it means you screwed up the connection strings you use.

Comment: Right that what was I gathered, thank you for the explanation. However, the question still remains, all of my apps are hosted on my Web Server but access a database on SQL or SQL Test boxes, that would be remote access yes? Yet they are working...but neither of my SQL boxes are granting DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ access.

Comment: Oh Also, I do expect to connect to SQL server as a SQL Login but I've posted my connection strings, I am not using Integrated Security=True option, what else could it be??

Comment: There are three possible explanations: 1) they use SQL auth instead of integrated auth (which seems to be the most plausible one, since you example has an userid and password in conn string) 2) they use integrated auth and run in an app poll that uses a different credential or 3) they use integrated auth but the ASP app impersonates the caller, thus triggering constrained delegation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739587%28WS.10%29.aspx.

Comment: Most likely is that your app is not using the connection string you expect it to use. Do you pass in a connection string to your datacontext constructor?

Comment: Not sure if I am or not to be honest, I just use SQL Metal to generate the LINQ-to-SQL classes. But when opening my .dbml file, the connection property is set to the one I want to use. Both the application I am getting this error with, and my other applications that are working, are in the same application pool, and both are using SQL auth.

Comment: You're going to have to track down how the data context generated from the .dbml is instantiated in your code.

Comment: I am not passing it anything, I just instantiate it with new MyDataContext()

Comment: The app pool its using a predefined identity of Network Service, not sure if that helps.

Comment: Well I feel stupid....but it seems like my Web App didn't get the most updated version of my class library dll, So I guess what happened was I built the class library to debug and not release and my web app was referencing release folder dll. This is the only explanation I can come up with because I just deleted the class library reference, re-built class library, re-added reference, and then re-published while choosing to delete all files on there, and it works...

Comment: Your web app project should reference the class library *project*, not the dll. Add the class library project to the web app solution, then remove the reference to the dll and add reference to the project. This way, when deploying or testing, the retail web app will reference retail class dll and debug will reference debug, automatically.

Comment: I'd like to add/clarify to Remus' very good answer that you can also receive this message if you need to add NetworkService to SQL. For example, this message will appear as domain\machine$ in the SqlClient exception, but if you're accessing a local instance of SQL, adding a login for the computer account will not fix the problem; you have to add NetworkService directly.

Comment: While this is all well and good, how do you add the machine login to SQL? -- They're both on the same domain, and I would prefer to use integrated security.  But just adding an account named "Domain\MachineName$" completely fails (like, it doesn't exist, and object explorer chokes and fails to find anything like that).

Comment: CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\MACHIN$] FROM WINDOWS;

Comment: @RemusRusanu - I followed this approach and didn't fix my issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 41):

This error occurs when you have configured your application with IIS, and IIS goes to SQL Server and tries to login with credentials that do not have proper permissions. This error can also occur when replication or mirroring is set up.
 I will be going over a solution that works always and is very simple.
Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties

In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

Comment: This was the solution for me since the web application and database are on the same machine.
I still got the error "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$" but adding the machine to SQL logins did not help, but adding "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" did.

Though you should not use the role db_owner unless it is needed, normaly db_datareader and db_datawriter is sufficient.

Answer (score 24):

Basically to resolve this we need to have some set up like

- Web App Running under ApplicationPoolIdentity
- Web Application connecting to databases through ADO.Net using Windows Authentication in the connection string

The connection string used with Windows authentication include either `Trusted_Connection=Yes`attribute or the equivalent attribute `Integrated Security=SSPI` in `Web.config` file

My database connection is in Windows Authentication mode. So I resolved it by simply changing the **Application Pools** Identity from **ApplicationPoolIdentity** to my domain log in credentials **DomainName\MyloginId**

Step:

1. Click on **Application Pools**
2. Select Name of your application
3. Go to **Advanced Setting**
4. Expand **Process Model** and click **Identity**. Click three
   dot on right end.
5. Click **Set...** button and Provide 
   your domain log in credentials

For me it was resolved.

**Note:** In Production or IT environment, you might have service account under same domain for app pool identity. If so, use service account instead of your login.

Comment: For the above question this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER

Answer (score 20):

In my case I had `Identity="ApplicationPoolIdentity"` for my IIS Application Pool.

After I added `IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationName` user to SQL Server it works.

Comment: I believe this will only work if IIS and the SQL server are on the same machine.

Comment: This worked for me! I have a local IIS-SQL server setup.

Comment: Thank you very much. This problem started for me after upgrading my local dev environment from SQL Server 2014 to 2017. Your suggestion was the silver bullet in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me also. What I would like to highlight is that the error message  is still 'Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$' even though 
 the application pool is set to run under pool identity and the login fails even if the  'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$' actually is granted the permissions to connect. Seems like misleading error message to me.

Answer (score 19):

The trick that worked for me was to remove `Integrated Security` from my connection string and add a regular `User ID=userName; Password=password` your connection string in the `App.config` of your libruary might not be using integrated security but the one created in `Web.config` is!

Comment: A billion thank-yous to you.  Huge, huge help.  Thank you, thank you, thank you.

This is, I'm sure, very obvious but for future folks, it's User Id=something; Password=something;

Comment: I was getting the same error in the title of the post. I found that the 'User Id= yourUserid Password= yourPassword' is ignored when  "'trusted connection=true'" is in the database connection string. I removed "'trusted connection=true'" from my string and that fixed my problem. This didn't happen until I moved the application from debugging in VS 2012 to iis 8.

Answer (score 12):

A colleague had the same error and it was due to a little configuration error in IIS.
The wrong Application Pool was assigned for the web application.

Indeed we use a custom Application Pool with a specific Identity to meet our needs.

In his local IIS Manager -> Sites -> Default Web Site -> Our Web App Name -> Basic Settings...
The Application Pool was "DefaultAppPool" instead of our custom Application Pool.

Setting the correct application pool solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I added `<identity impersonate="true" />` to my web.config and it worked fine.

Comment: Just understand this will change the context for which the ASP.NET application runs under in its entirety. Instead of running under the default 'NETWORK SERVICE' context it will now run under the context of the user using the application (i.e. Domain\someUser). This is OK sometimes, but just understand this change isn't just a quick fix to the OP and does have other downstream implications that may/may not be desired.

Comment: [MSDN on <identity />](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was resolved when I replaced the default Built-in account 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' with a network account which was allowed access to the database.

Settings can be made in Internet Information Server (IIS 7+) > Application Pools > Advanded Settings > Process Model > Identity

Answer (score 6):

For me issue with 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$' fixed by setting `DefaultApplicationPool` Identity to `NetworkService`.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me, not built in network but as a `custom account`. Basically you need to impersonate as an account to make all connections work.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can use Network Service or Authenticated User. 
Then give the Server Roles => public and sysadmin  
Then give the User Mapping => select your database and 
check public and db_owner.

Answer (score 3):

We had been getting similar error messages while processing an Analysis Services database. It turned out that the username, which was used to run the Analysis Services instance, had not been added to the SQL Server's Security Logins.

In SQL Server 2012, the SQL Server and Analysis services are configured to run as different users by default. If you have gone with the defaults, always ensure that the AS user has access to your datasource!

Comment: I had the same problem. The error from SSAS is the same, but the account is not Network Service. 
The account is actually: NT Service\MSOLAP$INSTANCENAME

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have

```
User Instance=true
```

in connection string. Try removing it which will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error with a SQL Server authenticated user

I tried some of the fixes, but they did not work.

The solution in my case was to configure its "Server Authentication Mode" to allow SQL Server authentication, under Management Studio: Properties/Security.

Answer (score 1):

The only point that everyone seems to have overlooked is that you may want integrated security = true. You may have the site running under a pool account. That's all fine so and it's still possible to hit the SQL server with the original user credential and not the pool's. It's called constrained delegation. If you enable it and set up an SPN windows will translate the pool's credentials with the user's on requests going to the final service (SQL is just one such service). You have to register the ONE AND ONLY SQL server that services SQL requests on the web server. Setting this all up is too much for me to try to accurately describe here. It took me quite a while to work through it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new answer in here because previous answers weren't explaining the issue I had. Problem is that the username required in SQL is the **NAME of the app pool, and not its identity**.

I ran in IIS with AppPools set to the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` identity.

My SQL Security User name with access was called `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` and it was working fine with a ASP.NET Full Framework .net application.

When launching my ASP.NET Core application, it created a new AppPool with the application name, but no CLR version and still using the same `ApplicationPoolIdentity` identity.

But after looking at the user name used via `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, I realized it isn't using DefaultAppPool, but the new app pool name. So I had to add a new user called `IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationName` in the SQL security tab, and not the default.

Answer (score 1):

My issue turned out to be in the Publish settings in Visual Studio. My appsettings.json connection string was correct, but the Database connection strings in the publish settings, had integrated security = true.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem in a **SharePoint 2016 environment.**

Troubleshooting identified the processes that were causing the error messages were PowerShell sessions running as SYSTEM on the SharePoint Servers.

**The issue was caused by having a PowerShell Profile for 'All Users, All Hosts' that loaded the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell PSSnappin.**

When the SYSTEM acct launched a PowerShell session, it would try to contact the SQL server and get information from the SharePoint Configuration database.
These attempts were denied and were reported as login attempts from Domain\ServerName.

**Resolution:**
Remove any PowerShell profile that activates a call to a SQL Server (ie the SharePoint Snappin) from the All Users locations, and place them directly in Current User locations for all users that need to have these preloaded.

Information on PowerShell Profiles from Microsoft here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: Welcome.  Nicely formatted and clear answer.  It might benefit from some additional information about how this ties to Sharepoint directly.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue earlier,removing `Persist Security Info=True` from connectionstring worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours trying to fix the issue and I finally got it - the SQL Server Browser was "Stopped". The fix is to change it to "Automatic" mode:

> If it is disabled, go to Control Panel->Administrative
>   Tools->Services, and look for the SQL Server Agent. Right-click, and
>   select "Properties." From the "Startup Type" dropdown, change from
>   "Disabled" to "Automatic".

[quote from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283641/1115382)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem when a client renamed a SQL Server. The SQL Reporting Service was configured to connect to the old server name, which they had also created an alias for that redirected to the IP of the new server name.

All of their old IIS apps were working, redirecting to the new server name via the alias. On a hunch, I checked if they were running SSRS. Attempting to connect to the SSRS site Yielded the error:

*"The service is not available.Contact your system administrator to resolve the issue. System administrators: The report server can’t connect to its database. Make sure the database is running and accessible. You can also check the report server trace log for details. "*

It was running on the server, but failing to connect because it was using the alias for the old server name. Re-configuring SSRS to use the new server name instead of the old/alias fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the App Pool Identity to Local System
2. On SQL Mgmt > Security > Logins

   1. Find NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM double click
   2. User Mappings > Check your database  and give it a role below.
   3. Remember also to create the user data base o security logins with a correct password.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to test a solution using the following

```
string cn = "Data Source=[servername];Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=[dbname];";
```

The way I solved was: I had to open Visual Studio and run it under another account, because the account I was using to open was not my Admin account.

So if your problem is similar to mine: pin the VS to the task bar, then use Shift and Right Click to open the menu so you can open VS as another user.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate there are a few good answers here, but as I've just lost time working this out, hopefully this can help someone.

In my case, everything had been working fine, then stopped for no apparent reason with the error stated in the question.

IIS was running as Network service and Network Service had been set up on SQL Server previously (see other answers to this post). Server roles and user mappings looked correct.

The issue was; for absolutely no apparent reason; Network Service had switched to 'Deny' Login rights in the database.

To fix:

1. Open SSMS > Security > Logins.
2. Right click 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' and Click Properties.
3. Go to 'Status' tab and set `Permission to Connect To Database Engine` To 'Grant'.

[image: Network Service Allowed]

Answer (score 0):

I had the \MACHINE$ account a part of the sysadmin role on the SQL server, and it didn't help. The server was on the same computer and IIS. App Pool identity was set to Network Service.

What helped me was changing App Pool from Integrated to Classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with a separate service id (AD) to connect to Database, it was working from Visual Studio 2019 but not in the Test or Production Server.

Made below changes which worked out for me, also find the connection details

```
"Server=ServerName;Database=dBName;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=DOMAIN\\ServiceId;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Then.. Change the Application Pool with Identity runs on the service id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz9me.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had all the settings (AppPool identity, AppPool on website, login for AppPool, etc.) correctly specified, but when I created the AppPool login with PowerShell, I forgot to grant connect permission (`-GrantConnectSql`) on the user, which by default is disabled.

```
Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance "." -LoginName $AppPoolUser -LoginType "WindowsUser" -Enable -GrantConnectSql
```

In order to fix this manually:

- Open SSMS
- Connect to the server
- Navigate to Security > Logins
- Open the AppPool user's properties
- Under the tab "Status"
- Set "Permission to connect to database engine" to "Grant"