# report viewer and grid-view did not display any thing after publishing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I created a website that had a report viewer and grid-view to display data from SQL server and also the website upload data from an excel sheet to a website.

When I run the website in a local machine every thing work fine, but when I published it and run it in IIS, report viewer and grid-view did not display any things and also data did not upload from an excel sheet..

I searched for a solution but I did not get any result..
Could anyone help me??

Comment: Are you getting any error message? What kind of data source you are using?

Comment: I did not get any error in a reportviwer

Comment: but in gridview a get this error (Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) and in excel sheet it direct to the login page..

Comment: The data source is sql

Comment: You may see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename

Comment: Thank you for the link but when I try to follow this (SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties

In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.)                   the error is changed to Login failed for user '.. name of the device..