# Unable to connect to SQL Using DSN from IIS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iis, dsn

I am trying to connect to a DSN in my machine through IIS. My code is like this

```
  internal class ODBCClass:IDisposable
    {
        private readonly OdbcConnection oConnection;

        private OdbcCommand oCommand;

        public ODBCClass(string DataSourceName)
        {
//Instantiate the connection
            oConnection = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=" + DataSourceName);
            try
            {
//Open the connection
                oConnection.Open();
//Notify the user that the connection is opened
                Console.WriteLine("The connection is established with the database");
            }
            catch (OdbcException caught)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(caught.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            oConnection.Close();
        }

        public OdbcCommand GetCommand(string Query)
        {
            oCommand = new OdbcCommand();
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
            oCommand.CommandText = Query;
            return oCommand;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            oConnection.Close();
        }
    }
public DataSet GetOrderData()
    {
        using (var o = new ODBCClass("TL"))
        {
            OdbcCommand oCommand = o.GetCommand("select * from Department");
            var oAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(oCommand);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            oAdapter.Fill(ds);
            //TO DO : Make use of the data set
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

This works properly when I run this as a console app through VisualStudio. But when I host this to IIS and try to run, it throws an error like this

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user &#39;WORKGROUP\vg$&#39;.
```

Comment: Check your app pool identity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename - different user.

Comment: @ElGavilan already Checked and made it to networkkusers . Still same issue

Comment: Did you grant permission to access database by the application. Try `sp_grantlogin 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use a System DSN, and not a User DSN. 
Also try passing in the username and password.
http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/ConnectionStrings/ODBCDSN/tabid/89/Default.aspx

You may also want to try to use a DSN-less connection.
http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/ConnectionStrings/ODBCDSNLess/tabid/90/Default.aspx

For older SQL Server versions, you can use "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"
http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForSQLServer

For newer SQL Server versions, use the "Microsoft SQL Server .NET Data Provider"
http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=86#SQLClientManagedProvider

HTH