# Getting "Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName$' " with Windows Server 2016, IIS 10

Tags: iis

I have asp.net web apps deployed on my windows server 2016. Database is on the same machine. When I try to access DB from my web app, I get error - "Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName$'"

Same setup works well on Windows Server 2012.
On WS2012 setup, a BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS gets added as a user in my DB on installation, but not on WS2016.
When I manually add this user on WS2016 setup, it works fine.

I assume this is because of something new in IIS 10.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: I am also getting same error

Comment: Please refer below mentioned link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename

Answer (score 0):

Got issue in our environment only. Our installer uses some binaries which were working to add IIS_IUSRS and those were not compatible for IIS10. Updating those helped.