# C# Active directory Principal display name is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

I am trying to display full name of user from active directory. It works fine on my local. But when I publish this code to IIS on server it shows display name as null. What may be the issue? My account is using windows authentication.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
                var displayName = principal?.DisplayName; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use HostingEnvironment.Impersonate() in order to access my AD properties on my IIS server. (It worked without it on local)

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
  // your code
}
```

Also, you'd have to change your Application Pool's identity from "AppPoolIdentity" to "NetworkService".

Comment: This throws  error Login failed for user 'DomainName\MachineName$'.

Comment: It's probably a permission issue. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806582/7046455)