# Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$' even after adding the Machine$ to the Login list

Tags: sql, tfsbuild

I was having difficulty with making the TFS build and tests run. Since my tests access the database on the build machine it is giving the following error:
`Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.`

I was googling around and found this post: [Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806582/2182401)

I added the `domain\machine$` to the SQL Login list with highest privileges, but still no luck. I still get the same error when my tests tries to access the DB. Is there something else that I should be aware of?

Comment: domain\machine$ wouldn't be an SQL login, it'd be a Windows credential.  I think you'd be better off using IntegratedSecurity with the AppPool rather than AppPoolIdentity and then apply the permissions for that account on the database.

Comment: Which kind of build are you using XAML or Vnext build? To narrow down if the issue is related to TFS build definition settings or build service account permission, you could **manually run your test on the build machine** to see if you could access the database successfully.