# Error: Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\PC-Name$'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have a MVC Application ,it is my connection string.

```
   <add name="BehkamContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Behkam;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Working with my project in debug I have no issues. However running it in IIS I am getting this error:

> Cannot open database "Behkam" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-TFB5NSL$'.

I use `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` but get error.

I set `Integrated Security=SSPI` in connection sting but get error.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Your application pool identity on IIS has no permission to read the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename)