# SQL Server 2012 login problem with a restored database

Tags: sql-server, authentication, restore

I took a backup and when I tried to restore it on another server, everything seemed to work perfectly, but I can not connect to it from any of my web applications or services.

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\user'.

I use an Active Directory technical user in my web application.

I ran this line due to its user:

```
USE database;    
ALTER USER [domain\user] WITH LOGIN = [domain\user]
```

I tried restore it in SSMS and with this code, too:

```
USE master;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE database
FROM DISK = 'U:\BACKUP\database.bak'
WITH RECOVERY,  
MOVE 'database' TO 'U:\DATA\database.mdf',
MOVE 'database_log' TO 'V:\LOG\database_log.ldf';
GO
```

I added the `db_datareader` and the `db_datawriter` and even the `db_owner` roles to the technical user.

I do not know what the problem is.

**UPDATE**
The source SQL Server version is 11.0.6567.0, the target version is 11.0.7001.0.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried this:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'domain\user', 'domain\user'
```

but it throws this error:

> Terminating this procedure. The User name 'domain\user' is absent or invalid.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map login (sql server) to user (database).

After restore, do those command, in that order :

```
CREATE LOGIN [domain\user] from windows
```

and

```
USE database;    
ALTER USER [domain\user] WITH LOGIN = [domain\user]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this line is not for that: ALTER USER [domain\user] WITH LOGIN = [domain\user]

Comment: On a new server, I think you have to create the login first.

Comment: The user came with the database but I tried to delete it and create a new one. It was useless.

Comment: Create the login (on the server), not the user (on the database).

Comment: @SándorHatvani: the security in SQL Server is **on two levels** - you have to have a **login** at the server level (and since this is at the **server** level, it's not part of your database backup!), and then you have a **user** (connected to that login) for each database he's allowed to use. So as Daniel has been telling you: you must **FIRST** create the **LOGIN** at the server level again, *before* you can reconnect the user in your database with that login .....

Comment: 1. I deleted the user than I run CREATE LOGIN [domain\user] from windows line. 2. I added db_datareader and db_datawriter to it on the datbase. 3. I run ALTER USER [domain\user] WITH LOGIN = [domain\user] line at the end. :(