# DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ login failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

we installed SQL Server 2019 and disabled SA account by internal it standards.
In errorlog file, below messages appeared (I suppose because of some internal processes) and there are a lot of them. If there is any process that connects DB and checks login? Please advice.

```
2021-11-11 22:10:05.26 Logon       Error: 18470, Severity: 14, State:
2021-11-11 22:10:05.26 Logon       Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'. Reason: The account is disabled. [CLIENT:
<local machine>]
```

MACHINENAME is database server where sql installed.
I am sure if to enable SA account - those messages will stop appearing in log file.

please advice, if there is any solution to keep SA account disabled and avoid checking which generates above messages in the log file?

Comment: Do you have any services which is running as `NETWORK SERVICE` or `LocalSystem`? If so, you should create a login and grant the desired privileges for the username `domain\machinename$` or you should change the authentication of such services to use an AD account and create the corresponding login and grant the necessary privileges.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename)

Comment: Yes, some services were under NT Service\Local Service. I changed them to AD Account. But problem remained.